# iOS Notification bar onBackground

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

OK, here is my question ( hope you will understand it :) ).

How to detect when the notification bar is sliding by the user ? I observed that when this happens my application goes in background. ( On Android is not happening this ). It is possible to make that when the notification view is "activated" the application stay in foreground ?

Comment: Why do you not just implement method `- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application` in your App Delegate class?

Comment: I did that. I would like to stay in foreground the application. I stated that the application goes in background, I know this because the application called the method didEnterBackground

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No that is not possible , that is iOS funcationality,

In iOS notifications that display a banner do not deactivate your app in the way that alert-based notifications do. Instead, the banner is laid along the top edge of your app window and your app continues receive touch events as before. However, if the user pulls down the banner to reveal the notification center, your app moves to the inactive state just as if an alert-based interruption had occurred. Your app remains in the inactive state until the user dismisses the notification center or launches another app. At this point, your app moves to the appropriate active or background state. The user can use the Settings app to configure which notifications display a banner and which display an alert.

From [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html).

You can use **applicationDidEnterBackground** appDelegate method for handling when app goes to background.

Comment: as I said in an earlier comment: I handled when the app goes to background. I hoped that maybe, somehow, is some hacky thing to make the application not go in background when the user pulls down the notification bar, like on Android where is not going to background

Comment: @user42949: and as i said, No that is not possible in iOS.